# How can I debug a C++ project by writing code on Windows but debuging on linux system

Tags: c++

I want to debug a large C++ project on my personal computer by visual GUI for convenience and compile on a remote Linux server.  I'm looking for a solution how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging the project in your computer means that you actually have to build the executable in your personal PC.Taking that into account means that the project **must** be cross platform for your windows pc and your linux server. If the code  is cross platform I would suggest to see the options with which you compile on the linux pc and copy them on the windows machine (for example if you use g++-10 with flags about c++17 on the server then you can build this project with the same configurations on Windows).That being said I don't encourage to develop your code on a pc that is so different from your target(s) ,it is not that difficult to dual boot or to create vm's if you want to try linux (with a gui) and then it will be (nearly) guaranteed that your project will compile on the server.If you are not interested in the above solution you could try windows linux subsystem or msys2 but the results will not be guaranteed

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I would like to debug my project in the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a linux like environment on windows by using Msys2 or the Windows subsystem for linux.

You can also configure your IDE to acess a debugger running over ssh, but the solution depends on the ide you are using. Here is the documentation for QtCreator, the one I am using: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-generic-linux.html